# Setting background color of Win32 dialog button (not owner-drawn)

Tags: winapi, button, dialog, background-color

Is it possible to set the background color of a dialog button in Win32 without using an owner-drawn button?

The following paints the background of every dialog item except the buttons (not owner-drawn):

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:

    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, bgEditColor);    

    return (INT_PTR)bgBrushCurrent; // a red brush created earlier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite explicit in the SDK docs for the message:

> Buttons with the BS_PUSHBUTTON,
>   BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, or BS_PUSHLIKE
>   styles do not use the returned brush.
>   Buttons with these styles are always
>   drawn with the default system colors.
>   Drawing push buttons requires several
>   different brushes-face, highlight, and
>   shadow-but the WM_CTLCOLORBTN message
>   allows only one brush to be returned.
>   To provide a custom appearance for
>   push buttons, use an owner-drawn
>   button.

Most Windows programs nowadays use the visual style selected by the user.  Recommended, add the [required manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx).